# Power Query (M) Table.SelectRows with Multiple Variables

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm writing some month over month aggregations for the value column.

[Sample Data Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mR_XakewDzV1yXsgPnkOtXSXNI_X6ZuPPz-L3ESt_Zg/edit?usp=sharing)

I've written the monthly cumulative function without too much trouble:

```
 Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows1", "Cumulative Value", each List.Sum(
 Table.SelectRows(
         #"Sorted Rows1", 
         (x) => x[Month Start] <= [Month Start]
         )
 [Value]), type number)
```

But am running into difficulties creating the MOM aggregation with the region included.

```
 Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Property Region Cumulative Value", each List.Sum(
 Table.SelectRows(
         #"Added Custom2", each 
         (x) => x[Month Start] <= [Month Start]
         ,(x) => x[Property Region] = [Property Region]      
         )
 [Value]))
```

Any ideas on how to rewrite the criteria syntax to achieve the correct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine (though your desired output seems wrong)

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
#"Sorted Rows1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{ {"Value", type number}}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn( #"Sorted Rows1","Cumulative Value",(x)=>List.Sum(Table.SelectRows( #"Sorted Rows1", each [Month Start] <= x[Month Start] and x[Property Region] = [Property Region])[Value]))
in  #"Added Custom1"
```

[image]

Comment: That worked!! Thanks. I needed to move the List.Sum earlier.